# Serve files on route with react native for web for stripe apple pay verification

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments, react-native-web

I am currently working on a React Native App, which uses React Native Web to serve the same codebase as a web app. In my project I implemented Stripe as my payment system and to use apple pay, and for the web part, I need to upload a merchant verification file to `/.well-known/{fileName}`. The file is a document without any file extension.

Since the project is React Native, there is no public folder, where I could put the file and since I am using Amplify to host the project, there is now way of creating the folder and file directly on the server.

So, to sum up my question: How can I add a folder and file to my React Native Web project, which is hosted on AWS Amplify?

- I tried creating a new screen/route with React Navigation and put a WebView in there, put that just seems overkill

Answer (score 0):

When your project is structured in a regular manner, the `/.well-know` folder should be added to your `/public` folder. This is where your public files like the `index.js` file and `manifest.json` file should live as well.

I hope this helps.